# how to chain cy.request().then()?

Tags: asynchronous, cypress

#### Description

I cannot find a way to resolve data in `cy.request().then()` with using a `Cypress.Promise`:

#### Code

```js
 it('get inst state', () => {
    getInstState().then(res => {
      console.log('res: ', res);
    });

function getInstState() {
  return cy.request({
    url: 'instances/state',
    headers,
  }).then(res => {
    expect(res.status).equal(200);
   // do something
    return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}
```

#### Result

I return a `Cypress.Promise` instance in `cy.request().then()`, but  this code always logs `res:  null`,  so i cannot use the next `.then()` to get my response result

I want to chaining `cy.request()` like this:

```js
 it('get inst state', () => {
    getInstState().then(res => {
      console.log('res: ', res);
      instAction(res).then(actionResult => {
         console.log(actionResult)
        // next request;
      })
    });

function getInstState() {
  return cy.request({
    url: 'instances/batch/state',
    headers,
  }).then(res => {
    expect(res.status).equal(200);
   // do something
    return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}

function instAction(res) {
  expect(res.status).equal(200);
  const items = res.body.items;
  return cy.request({
    url: '/instances/action',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      instances: items.map(item => item.inst_id),
      action: 'server_off',
    },
  }).then(res => {
    cy.log('server_off inst', res);
    expect(res.status).equal(200);
    return res;
  });
}
```

how to make `cy.request().then()` can chaining the next `.then()`?

#### Versions

Cypress@4.4.0

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of using `Cypress.promise()` in your case:

```
function getInstState() {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cy.request({
        url: 'instances/batch/state',
        headers,
    }).then(res => {
        expect(res.status).equal(200);
        // do something
        resolve(res);
        // handle reject
    });
  });
}
```